# how do i pass argument into a function inside a function?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

My string of code currently is:

```
def makeTriangle(sign):
    
    def triangle(n):
        result = ''
    
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            result += sign * i + '\n'
        
        return result
    
    return
```

how do i actually pass the sign from MakeTriangle(sign) into triangle(n) using higher order function?

Comment: `sign` is already accessible within `triangle` thanks to how scoping works.

Comment: you need to return triangle from makeTriangle

Comment: Change `return` to `return triangle`

Comment: So you don't want to "pass an argument `sign` into `triangle` inside a `makeTriangle`", you want to use `makeTriangle(sign)` to return a `triangle` that captures/remembers the `sign`. Passing an argument specifically means that you're trying to do `triangle(sign)`, what you want is a closure.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return *triangle* otherwise it's thrown away.  Since this pattern seems to cause some confusion:

```py
def makeTriangle(sign):
    
    def triangle(n):
        result = ''
    
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            result += sign * i + '\n'
        
        return result
    
    return triangle # returns a function wrapped in an enclosing scope


triangle_maker = makeTriangle("+")
# triangle_maker is a `triangle()` function, locked in a scope where `sign=+`.
triange_maker(3)
# calls the `triangle()` function
```

The other option for this pattern is to use `functools.partial`:

```py
from functools import partial

def triangle(sign, n):
    result = ""
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result += sign * i + "\n"
    return result

# call without caching arg:
triangle("+",3)
# make partial function:
plus_triangle = partial(triangle, "+")
plus_triangle(3)
```

This saves one having to write out the container function every time, but it is of course much more limited than a full closure.

Comment: +1 for namedropping `partial` because that's the intent of most practical closures, and it saves you the effort of writing a nested function that uses variables outside its scope, which makes bugs easier and tests harder.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I love partial (and functools in general).  But I think the habit comes from JS.  Ofc, closures are really useful when you *actually* need them.  Although most closures I've ever written have morphed into classes when they got too much state to be manageable.